# How to practically estimate the maximum usable resolution from a scanner using Fourier transform?

Tags: resolution, scanning

I can use an Epson V750 Pro to scan negatives. According to [Filmscanner.info](https://filmscanner.info/EpsonPerfectionV750Pro.html) the maximum usable resolution is about 2300 dpi, but I would like to check myself what the one I can use can do.

I don't have a USAF test pattern, obviously. How can I estimate the level of details I can achieve at increasing resolutions?

What I think could work is to scan at increasing resolution a single flat object (no motion between scans) which offers enough details down to 6400 dpi, and analyse via Fourier transform the frequencies. I guess that at a certain point the transformed image will have dark pixels around a centre region, like shown [here](https://smallpond.ca/jim/misc/resolution/fft/index.html).

However, how to proceed further, and which object is suitable to provide details down to 6400 dpi size? I cannot trust film, since grain is likely not that small and it has no really sharp edges at the edges.

Comment: Is all the film the same emulsion and speed? Otherwise your absolute resolution from the negatives can vary greatly from one film stock to the next.

Comment: @MichaelC the question is about estimating the scanner usable resolution, not the film resolution

Comment: The theoretical resolution of the scanner only applies independently of other factors if the object being scanned has continuous lines. No photographic negative has continuous lines. So your maximum achievable resolution will always involve an interaction of both the scanner's resolution limits, the film's resolution limits, AND how the differences in those two limits interact. Have you ever tried to look through two screen doors at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

You can look for shots in your collection with an object that has some very small patterns, for example a net. When you see the squares on the net not distinguishable then you'll find your optimal resolution.